# Angular Dart providers

Tags: javascript, angular, dart

I want to make GET by web app on angular dart, but I have error in console when I try to open page with app:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid argument(s): No provider found for Client0.
```

And this entrypoint

```
void main() {
  bootstrap(AppComponent, [BrowserClient]);
}
```

And I have only one component from and one default component, because I use `AngularDart Web App - a web app with material design component` template from Web Storm:

```
@Component(
  selector: 'watch-counter',
  styleUrls: const [
    'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
    'watch_counter_component.css'],
  templateUrl: 'watch_counter_component.html',
  directives: const [
    CORE_DIRECTIVES,
    materialDirectives,
  ],
  providers: const [UserService]
)
class WatchCounterComponent implements OnInit {

  final UserService userService;

  WatchCounterComponent(this.userService);

  int tabIndex = 0;

  void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    tabIndex = event.newIndex;
  }

  final loginModalTabs = const<String>[
    'Login',
    'Registration'
  ];

  @override
  Future<Null> ngOnInit() async {
  }
}
```

And with this service

```
@Injectable()
class UserService {

  final Client http;
  UserService(this.http);

  dynamic extractData(Response resp) => JSON.decode(resp.body)['data'];

  Future login(String login, String password) async {
    print("login");
  }

  void register() {
    print("register");
  }

}
```

All failings when I add http Client into service.

Comment: This is not enough information to provide help. Can you provide a more full example of the code that is failing, not just the few lines you have above?

Comment: @matanlurey thanks, I added more details. I really cannot understand what problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are providing `BrowserClient` but injecting a `Client`.

Change your `bootstrap` to:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
]);
```

I don't believe `BrowserClient` is marked with `@Injectable()`, so you might need:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  provide(Client, useFactory: () => new BrowserClient()),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or add in the bootstrap (or the Componente `providers` list):

```
const clientProvider = [
  ClassProvider(Client, useClass: BrowserClient),
];
```